# How can I deprecate an entire protocol?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, protocols, deprecated

Is it possible to deprecate an entire protocol?  I'm using the GCC compiler that is shipped with iOS SDK 5.0 Beta 7.

`DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE` doesn't seem to work.

For example, the following two statements do not compile.

- `@protocol DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE MyProtocol`
- `@protocol MyProtocol DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but I think that the following syntax should work.

```
__attribute__ ((deprecated))
@protocol MyProtocol
@end
```

This parallels the syntax for deprecating an entire interface as well as a single method.

```
__attribute__ ((deprecated))
@interface MyClass
@end

@interface MyClass2
- (void) method __attribute__((deprecated));
@end
```

Comment: Huh.  Totally didn't think about that.

Comment: I realize this is old, but just as a sidenote, as of recent Clang versions you can just use: ```__deprecated``` as shorthand for ```__attribute__ ((deprecated))```.

Comment: `__deprecated` has nothing to do with clang versions.  It's provided by the system headers in /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h.  You can also use `__deprecated_msg("A note to the developers using it.")` and the compiler print the message along with the deprecation notice.